# sql express 2012 on vs 2010 with ssdt not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express, sql-server-data-tools

I have visual studio 2010 installed and working on my computer.
recently I have updated sql express 2008 to sql 2012. after visual studio prompted

> "this server version is not supported. only servers up to Microsoft SQL
>   server 2008 are suported"

I have installed sql server data tools (from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650014) to solve this problem, however unfortunately it keeps showing the message.
What am I doing wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: can you update your vs?

Comment: Im not quite sure. im working on a school project and my school only have vs 2010 so I need to be compatible with it. is newer version of vs projects are compatible with vs 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet will be to install the latest version of SSDT from Microsoft. VS DB Projects stopped support with SQL 2008. SSDT for SQL 2010 stopped support w/ SQL 2012, I think.  You don't need a license for the VS shell, though you might need to sign up w/ the MS developer program.

Go here for the SSDT blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/  You should see the most recent post or two pointing to the current release. This should support 2012+ without any issues. It will install the VS IDE if you don't have it installed.

FYI, the version you pointed to *should* work with SQL 2012, but you'd be better off using the latest version that is currently under active development.  Ideally, the dacpac should be able to be used regardless of which version of SSDT you're using.

It might be worth checking to see what you're turning in. If you can turn in a script, it won't matter what version of SSDT you use. If you need to turn in the dacpac, you might have to double-check your install for SQL Express and SSDT to be sure they are the proper versions.

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand, the versions of ssdt in the link are for visual studio 2015. will it work on vs 2010?

Comment: The installer will install a free, limited version of Visual Studio 2015 on your computer if you do not already have Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: So, no - this link will not work w/ VS2010. However, it _is_ the latest version of SSDT.  From everything I can see, the link you posted should install the proper SSDT for SQL 2012 bits.  I'm relatively sure that I was working w/ VS2010 and SQL 2012 for a while.  Is VS2010 an absolute requirement or can you use the latest SSDT bits to do the DB part and VS2010 to do the code?